Two for loops and the second starts with i+1
I need some help with generating an image. (Disclaimer: Most of it is ChatGPT generated). It is compiling so the warning isn't too serious, but it still bothers me and I can't think of a solution to fix it:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\newcount\numPoints
\numPoints=25

\newcommand{\generatepoints}[1]{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{rand}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{rand}
        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=0.3pt] (p\i) at (\x,\y) {};
        \global\expandafter\xdef\csname px\i\endcsname{\x}
        \global\expandafter\xdef\csname py\i\endcsname{\y}
    }
}

\newcommand{\connectpoints}[1]{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
        \foreach \j in {\i,...,#1} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xi}{\csname px\i\endcsname}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yi}{\csname py\i\endcsname}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xj}{\csname px\j\endcsname}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yj}{\csname py\j\endcsname}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\xj - \xi}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{\yj - \yi}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{sqrt((\dx)*(\dx) + (\dy)*(\dy))}
            \ifdim \dist cm < 0.3cm % Hier die Distanz anpassen
                \draw (p\i) -- (p\j);
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \generatepoints{\numPoints}
        \connectpoints{\numPoints}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Konfettiperkolation mit 25 Punkten}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


The problem is, that you cant add a +1 in the second for loop in connectpoints, because the system can't connect the variable names. But if I compile it like that I get the warning, that I want to connect a dot with itself.
Thank you for helping:)
Also if you have a more elegant solution that would be nice too, but I tried around for quite some time.

Ok, i did so. Thanks for the hint

\ifnum\i=\j \else \draw (p\i) -- (p\j); \fi   . But what on earth is the \global here \global\expandafter\xdef meant to do?

? How shall your drawing look like? Can you post a sketch or so? // Personally, I don't rely on ChatGPT. However, you may want to try again with a dedicated adaptation for programmers? phind.com

@MS-SPO it should represent confetti percolation. But it is solved :)

You could just do
\foreach[count=\ii from 1] \i in {2,...,#1} {
  \foreach \j in {1,...,\ii} {

which removes any necessity for calculating anything by letting the loop count an offset to \i.
You can use the \inteval macro which provides a nice top-level interface for integer calculations by \numexpr:
\foreach \i in {1,...,\inteval{#1-1}} {
  \foreach \j in {\inteval{\i+1},...,#1} {

The PGFFor package includes the parse key to evaluate the last element of a list but it is a bit bugged and uncomfortable to use:
\foreach[parse=true] \i in {1,...,0+int(#1-1)} {
  \foreach[parse=true] \j in {\the#1,...,0+int(\i+1)} {


Here are two different but very similar approaches.
Both use the PGFMath function veclen which calculates the square root of the sum of two squares faster and/or more precise.
Both check the distances to previously placed nodes directly after placing a new node. A TeX-level \ifnum is used to check whether previously placed nodes even exist.
The first one doesn't even store the random numbers but calculates the distances on a canvas level and does the check with a TeX-level \ifdim as well.
The second one does store the random numbers in value-keys which will later get accessed by \pgfkeysvalueof (which is a nice wrapper around a \csname).
I'm opting to not use global definitions (PGFKeys never are anyway) which prohibits me to use PGFFor's \foreach which groups its body (that's why you need the \xdef in your solution). The .list handler is a simple loop that doesn't group its body.
Instead of the calc functionality, I'm using PGFFor's evaluate key to calculate the distance as well whether its below the target.
If it is, the style style short gets tried, otherwise style long which is simply set to move to, i.e. it doesn't draw a line.
Since this is all done on one path, I'm able to also add gray circles around the dots to show the target distance.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\numPoints{25}
\newcommand*\numDist{.3}
\tikzset{
  bgdot/.style={
    shape=circle, opacity=.1, fill=gray, behind path,
    at=(\tikzlastnode), minimum size=2*\numDist cm, inner sep=+0pt},
  dot/.style={shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+.3pt}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \foreach[count=\ii from 0] \i in {1, ..., 25}
    \node[dot] (p\i) at (rand, rand) {}
      \ifnum\ii>0 % unless it's the first point
        let \p0=(p\i) in
        foreach \j in {1, ..., \ii}{
          let \p1=(p\j), \n0={veclen(\x1-\x0,\y1-\y0)} in
          \ifdim\n0<\numDist cm\relax
            (p\i) edge (p\j)
          \fi
        }
      \fi;

\tikz[
  dot/.append style={append after command={node[bgdot]{}}},
  /utils/exec={%
    \newcommand*\getX[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/macn/#1/x}}%
    \newcommand*\getY[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/macn/#1/y}}},
  style long/.style=move to,
  macn/.style={
    macn/#1/x/.initial/.evaluated=rand, % evaluate and store in key
    macn/#1/y/.initial/.evaluated=rand, % evaluate and store in key
    insert path={
      node[dot] (p#1) at (\getX{#1}, \getY{#1}) {}
        \ifnum#1>1 % unless it's the first point
          foreach[
            evaluate={
              \dist=veclen(\getX{#1}-\getX{\j},\getY{#1}-\getY{\j});
              \style=ifthenelse(\dist<\numDist,"short","long");}]
            \j in {1, ..., \inteval{#1-1}}{
            (p#1) edge[style \style/.try] (p\j)
          }
        \fi
    }
  }]\path[macn/.list={1, ..., 25}];
\end{document}

Output

